# Make loading data from database to combobox faster

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, firebird

I am loading 2 values from database to my combobox as displaymember and valuemember.

Here is my code for that:

```
private void LoadPartners()
{
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(Properties.Resources.connectionString_EB))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT PARTNERID, PARTNERNAME FROM PARTNERS", con))
        {
            List<Int_String> list = new List<Int_String>();
            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Int_String { _int = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), _string = dr[1].ToString() });
            }

            partner_cmb.DataSource = list;
            partner_cmb.ValueMember = "_int";
            partner_cmb.DisplayMember = "_string";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
} //Load all partners inside combobox
```

In my database I have around 10k rows and it took this function to load about 67ms. Is there any faster way of doing this since my `InitializeComponents()` take about 70ms and one more function is same as that so in total this 3 functions does 210ms, and with other smaller functions my form takes about 2 sec to load my form which is frustrating. Is there any way to get this function to work faster?

Comment: First thing to say: what do you do with 10K rows in a combobox? Surely you don't expect your user to scroll this list to find the item to select right?

Comment: 67ms for 10,000 rows is pretty fast. You could load the data in a background thread (BackgroundWorker or async/await) once the form has loaded.

Comment: @Steve it is combobox with write/search

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That is good idea. I will do it with that. Thanks

Comment: @UProduction it's still 10k rows in a combo box, which is still a bad idea